# trying to use "or" operator elegantly

Tags: python, regex

I have a small bit of regex that I use to generate a new string:

```
someinput = "some/very/long/string"

changedinput = re.match("(.*\/)", str(thisDir)).group(1)[:-1]
```

I use `.group(1)[:-1]` to get the actual string, and this code needs to work for all kinds of strings.

If the inputstring here is *"blbalba"*, then there is not match, and the regex will return Nonetype, therefore, this error appears when the grou() call is made:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I could solve with a construction like this:

```
someinput = "some/very/long/string"
tmp = re.match("(.*\/)", str(bla))# .group(1)[:-1]
if (tmp):
    changedinput = tmp.group(1)[:-1]
else:
    changedinput = ""
```

It does annoy me though that I need **six** lines of code for this very simple construct.
So I started searching for something like a elvis constructor in python, and found the **"or"** operator.
I then thought I could maybe do something like this:

```
someinput = "some/very/long/string"
changedinput = re.match("(.*\/)", str(someinput)).group(1)[:-1] or ""
```

The issue here of cause, is that if there is not match, then the group() call will throw the same error again.

Is there any way I can do this, in very few lines of code, in a nice and pythonic way?

Comment: The last four lines can be replaced with `changedinput = tmp.group(1)[:-1] if tmp else ""`

Comment: you could also just not capture the `\/` by using the regex `(.*)\/`. This way, group 1 will already be correct

Comment: `or` will not be able to work for all test cases in this context btw.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
changedinput = tmp.group(1)[:-1] if tmp else ""
```

This is also more "pythonic" in that it's even less code, but it is less efficient since you are calling `re.match()` twice:

```
changedinput = re.match("(.*\/)", str(someinput)).group(1)[:-1] if re.match("(.*\/)", str(someinput)) else ""
```

Comment: yeah, great this works. For a second I was a bit nervous that python did'nt have lazy evaluation, but this works

Comment: Great. If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to accept it as an answer so others can use it, too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an assignment expression:

```
changedinput = (tmp.group(1)[:-1] 
                if (tmp := re.match("(.*\/)", str(someinput))
                else "")
```

`re.match` is called and its return value is assigned to `tmp` before it is evaluated in a boolean context. If it is true, the value of `tmp` is used to call `group` rather than calling `re.match` a second time.